# anaconda python 3.5 install PyQt4

Tags: pyqt4, anaconda

Recently (like two months ago) Anaconda moved from PyQt4 to PyQt5. I realized this when I freshly installed it on a new windows machine, and my old code wouldn't run. Is there a (relatively easy) way to also install PyQt4 along PyQt5 with Anaconda running on Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install the PyQt4 version from a separate channel, but it will downgrade the PyQt5 version that you currently have installed.

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge pyqt
```

One way around this is to create an additional anaconda environment and install it from there.

**In the Windows Command Prompt:**

```
# Create the environment
conda create -n py35_qt4 python=3.5 anaconda


# Activate the new environment
activate py35_qt4


# Install the PyQt4 package in the new environment
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge pyqt
```

Then, when you want to use the new PyQt4 environment, you will need to use the `activate py35_qt4` command to get into that environment, or add the path to that environment (similar to `C:\Anaconda3\envs\py35_qt4\python.exe`) to your IDE.

Comment: Is this still the best way to get PyQt4 with Anaconda?

Comment: C:\Anaconda\envs\Python27\Scripts> conda install --name EnvName --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge pyq
t=4 works for me

Comment: Now, in 06/2020, this does not work anymore--incompatible specifications.